# Simulator reset issue: “data” couldn’t be removed because you don’t have permission to access it

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I drag and drop the two images and some reason I want to reset the simulator,but when I am going to reset the simulator it give the this error even I deleted that images from photo library.

[image]

Comment: did you login as administrator?

Comment: yes, before adding that two images, I reset it two

Comment: Quit the simulator and do Reset.

Comment: @DhanasManian thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

**How to resolve:**

```
1. Go to: /Users/YourUserName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices.
2. Delete simulator folder Ex(84842644-331C-4E27-91E0-B524CF430E19).
3. Add new simulator: Xcode, scheme, simulator, (Add Additional Simulators..)
```

**Good Luck All!**

Answer (score 1):

I quit the simulator and again did reset and content settings it worked for me. Hope that helps.